# Specify order of imports in mongo-connector

Tags: python, mongodb, neo4j

I'm working with writing a `DocumentManager` for the Python `mongo-connector` project. On running the connector for the first time, all of my data is imported from MongoDB to a graph database (Neo4J) by the `bulk_upsert` function. However, the data has some dependencies amongst itself and I'd like one collection to be imported before the other. Concretely, I'd like `app.songs` to be imported before `app.playlists` as the latter has graph edges to the former. Currently the `mongo-connector` is doing all imports without any apparent order. Is there a way I can specify the order? If not, what can I do myself to ensure order?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`MERGE` Cypher statement](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) along with a uniqueness constraint the order in which the collections are imported shouldn't matter.

For example:

Let's say you have data that looks like this:

**playlists collection**

```
{
    "_id': "playlist1",
    "songIds": ["song1, song2, song3"]
}
```

**songs collection**

```
{
    "_id": "song1",
    "title": "Redemption Song",
    "artist": "Bob Marley"
}
```

Each playlist has a unique `_id` and each song has a unique `_id` which is referenced from the playlists document.

The Cypher statements to handle these documents would be something like this:

For playlists:

```
MERGE (p:Playlist {_id: {_id}})
UNWIND songIds AS songId
MERGE (p)<-[:IN_PLAYLIST]-(s:Song {_id: songId})
```

For songs:

```
MERGE (s:Song {_id: {_id}})
SET s.title = {title},
    s.artist = {artist}
```

`MERGE` is essentially "get or create". Here we use `MERGE` with the song ids, so if a node doesn't exist with a given song id it will be created. If it already exists, then it will be bound to the variable specified.

Be sure to create uniqueness constraints:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Playlist) ASSERT i._id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (s:Song) ASSERT s._id IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: I don't think this would help me because information of each `song` in the `playlists` is not enough to describe a complete song.